# How do I use mongodb to update a map?

Tags: typescript, mongodb

I want to update my call to the mongodb to be able to change just 1 value within a map object in the database and can't find any documentation to do this. Some documentation here:

https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/db.collection.updateOne/

working example:

```
db.collection.updateOne(
   <query>,
   [
      { $set: { status: "Modified" } }
   ]
)
```

idea of what I want:

```
const subThingString = "thing." + item.subThingType;
db.collection.updateOne(
   <query>,
   [
      { $set: { subThingString: "Modified" } }
   ]
)
```

data:

```
{
  {"thing": Object
   {
      "default": [],
      "other": []
   }
}
```

Then when I do a put I only want to update the array in "other"

Comment: can you provide any mocked data? and your desired response?

Comment: @AmirJani added some info including example data